# How to speed up Webpack 'optimize assets' stage.. (takes like 5 seconds)

Tags: webpack

My development process is slowed down by Webpack's  'optimize assets' stage which takes like 5 seconds...

as you can see here:
[image]

here is the config: https://github.com/born2net/studioEnterprise/blob/master/webpack.config.js

will appreciate any tips on optimizing this...

Sean.

Comment: Do you use `--watch` when start webpack?

Comment: I do yes as I like it to auto update when I save

Comment: I see, you have the most slow `source-map` method. How it goes without it?

Comment: tried but yes same...

Comment: Do you run it on virtual machine?

Comment: nope, a super fast i7 PC and no VM

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a [perf problem in ts-loader](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/issues/78).

Either TypeScript needs to [expose a dependency graph](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5192) in its API, or ts-loader needs to implement one internally.